# Imprimir reporte pdf con datos en bloques

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-8

Saludos estimados amigos, tengo un pequeño problema, necesito imprimir un documento en pdf, los datos los extraigo de una consulta.

Puedo imprimirlos en una tabla correctamente pero el detalle es que los datos de cada registro deben de ir en columnas individuales.

```
Codigo en el controlador
if($request['imprimir']==1){
                for ($i=0; $i < count($fichas) ; $i++) { 
                    if ($fichas[$i]!=null) {
                        $datos_fichas[] = Fichas::find($fichas[$i]);
                    }
                   
                }
               
                $pdf = \PDF::loadView('layouts_pdf.imprimir_fichas',compact('datos_fichas'));
                return $pdf->download('Fichas.pdf');
            }


Codigo de la vista
<table>
       
            @foreach ($datos_fichas as $ficha)
            <tr>                
              
                <td>
                    
                    Plan:{{$ficha->plans->nombre}}
                    Usuario:{{$ficha->usuario}}
                    Clave:{{$ficha->clave}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    
                    Plan:{{$ficha->plans->nombre}}
                    Usuario:{{$ficha->usuario}}
                    Clave:{{$ficha->clave}}
                </td>
                <td>
                   
                    Plan:{{$ficha->plans->nombre}}
                    Usuario:{{$ficha->usuario}}
                    Clave:{{$ficha->clave}}
                </td>
        
    
            </tr>

            @endforeach
            
            
            
        
        </table>
```

Solo quiero imprimir tres columnas,la cantidad de filas depende de la cantidad de registros.
Es decir si tengo 20 registros deben de haber 20 filas con 3 columnas

Estoy usando la librera DOMPDF

Comment: Hola Yoel. ¿Que librería estas usando para generar el PDF? Presioná [edit] para agregar el código que has realizado.

Comment: no veo el codigo con el que se genera el PDF... debes agregarlo

Comment: Listo amigos le hice unas ediciones al post